# 3 condition python while loop regarding checking if two dates are the same

Tags: python-2.x

I'm currently working on this problem of counting how many days between two dates including leap years.
However it keeps skipping the loop from the beginning, even though the two months and days aren't the same?

```
def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    day_count = 0
    while (year2 != year1) and (month2 != month1) and (day2! = day 1): 
       # print "in loop" // tester
        if (day2 != 0):
            day2 = day2 - 1
            day_count = day_count + 1
        else:
            if(month2 != 0):
                month2 = month2 - 1
                if month2 == (9 or 4 or 6 or 11):
                    day2 = 30
                if month2 == 2:
                    day2 = 28
                if (month2 == 2) and (year2 % 4):
                    day2 = 29
                else:
                    day2 == 31
            else:

                year2 = year2 - 1
                month2 = 12
    #print day_count //tester
    return day_count

# Test routine

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Comment: I regret to say that few programmers on SO are willing to debug this much code. You need to put some diagnostic print statements in to find the mistake. That's one thing. The other is that you're re-inventing the wheel. There are several Python libraries for working with dates, and numerous questions on SO about using them. You have only to query for those for a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> diff = datetime(2012, 2, 28)-datetime(2012, 1, 1)
>>> diff.days
58
```